# python bs4 attribute error

Tags: android, python

I am trying to crawl android apps from google play store. I am trying to use the code from the following link: http://blog.singhanuvrat.com/tech/crawl-google-play-to-get-list-of-all-apps

But when i run the code, i get the following error. Can anyone help me on this?

```
A fresh start ...
Type =  free  Category =  BOOKS_AND_REFERENCE
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "textop.py", line 182, in <module>
    getApps( url )
  File "textop.py", line 159, in getApps
    apps, skipped_apps = getTopAppsData( url, start_idx, size, app_type )
  File "textop.py", line 147, in getTopAppsData
    app_details = getAppDetails( title.get( 'href' ) )
  File "textop.py", line 94, in getAppDetails
    price = price_buy_span.find_all( 'span' )[-1].get_text().strip()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'
```

Answer (score 0):

`price_buy_span` is `None`. It is `None` because the preceding line failed to find a tag:

```
price_buy_span = soup.find( 'span', {'class' : 'price buy'} )
```

and *that* is because there is (no longer) such a span in the page. That class is now put on a button.

You'll have to adjust the code to work with the current HTML of the page instead, or ask the *blog author* to fix their example.

Answer (score 0):

**Handle your exception via Exception Handling in Python.**

Eg,

`try:
    price_buy_span = soup.find( 'span', {'class' : 'price buy'} )
    price = price_buy_span.find_all( 'span' )[-1].get_text().strip()
except:
    price_buy_span = ""`

or you can use if condition too.

`if soup.find('span',{'class' :'price buy'}):<br/>
    price = price_buy_span.find_all( 'span' )[-1].get_text().strip()
else:
    price ="`